# Remote debugging not hitting methods in the stream functions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, remote-debugging

I was trying to debug the application but have seen that you can able to debug the streams but not functions called from map or filter. In my case it is not hitting the break point inside calculateUserData. I tried it in IntelliJ Idea with the below code.

```
public String transformToUserData(Map<String, Integer> userIds) {
    return userIds
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(this::calculateUserData)
            .toString();
}

private String calculateUserData(Integer userId) {
    User user = userRegistrationService.getUser(Long.valueOf(userId));
    return user.toString();
}
```

Comment: I had something similar in Eclipse (normal debugging session). Turned out I needed to add the jdk source zip to the debugger classpath, otherwise it would just skip over such calls.

Comment: You need to call a terminal operation to begin traversing the elements. `toString()` is not a terminal operation.

Comment: Good point @Tunaki, it didn't strike me.